# How do I overlay a set of functions onto a ggplot2 graph when the function relies on the parameters of the inherited datafame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Effectively what I want to do is more efficiently generate a graph like this
using reproducible data that I am providing.

[image: Woolf Hanes Plot with Competitive Models]

I have plotted experimental data points of {[Substrate concentration], ([Substrate Concentration] / velocity) grouped by [Inhibitor Concentration]. Each of the lines is a continuous function that accepts the parameters `Substrate_Conc` and `Inhibitor_Conc`.

This is somewhat difficult for me to have to plot a function that relies on two inherited parameters.

For instance it is easy to plot a function that relies on one inherited parameter x, but `x` cannot be specified as an argument to my knowledge.

```
fx <- function(x){return(1 / x)}
ggplot() + theme_bw() + xlim(c(1, 100)) + stat_function(fun = fx, col = "black") + labs(x = "x", y = "y")
```

[image: Graph of f(x) = 1 / x]

This simply plots the graph of 1 / x, but I cannot specify `x` as a parameter

In my case I need to specify `x = Substrate_Conc` and also another parameter `Inhibitor_Conc` which I have grouped by.

My code:

```
library(dplyr) # For %>% operator 
library(ggplot2) # for plots
library(scales) # for pretty_breaks()
library(stats) # For nls() function

# Construct a dataframe of experimental Inhibitor Concentration with corresponding substrate concentrations 
# And with corresponding velocities
df <- data.frame(Inhibitor_Conc = rep(c(0,6,12,24), each = 5), 
                 Substrate_Conc = rep(c(2,5,10,20,50), times = 4),
                 velocity = c(0.0552, 0.1128, 0.1476, 0.1799, 0.2261,0.0242, 0.0690, 0.0774, 0.1905,0.1861,
                              0.0231, 0.0420,0.0979, 0.1329,0.1722,0.0138,0.0393,0.0855,0.1042,0.1562))

# Compute S_over_V for the Woolf_Hanes Plot
df <- df %>% 
      mutate(S_over_V = Substrate_Conc/velocity)

# Fit a function to describe this dataset. The Competitive Model is the best model to describe this enzyme kinetics dataset.
# But I will get around to fitting the other kinetic models such as Uncompetitive for comparison. 
Competitive_Fit <- nls(data = df, formula = velocity ~ (V_Max * Substrate_Conc) / (K_M * (1 + Inhibitor_Conc/K_I) + Substrate_Conc), 
                       start = list(K_M = median(df$Substrate_Conc), K_I = median(df$Substrate_Conc), V_Max = max(df$velocity)), 
                       control = nls.control(maxiter = 100))

# Print a summary of the fit: It is pretty good. 
print(summary(Competitive_Fit))

# Extract the parameters. First entry is K_M, following by K_I, followed by V_Max
Parameters <- coefficients(Competitive_Fit)

Competitive_Woolf_H_Function <- function(S, K_M, K_I, V_Max, I)
                      {
                        # Where S is the substrate concentration, and I is the inhibitor concentration
                        predicted_S_over_V = ((K_M / V_Max) + ((1 / V_Max)*S) + (K_M / (V_Max * K_I)) * I)
                        return(predicted_S_over_V)
                      }

# First construct a pretty Woolf Hanes Plot without any fitting:
# Construct a Woolf Hanes Plot simply a plot a {(Substrate Concentration) / (Velocity)} vs Substrate Concentration
Woolf_Hanes_Plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Substrate_Conc, y = S_over_V)) + theme_bw() + 
                    geom_point(aes(group = factor(Inhibitor_Conc), col = factor(Inhibitor_Conc), shape = factor(Inhibitor_Conc))) + 
                    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, col = "black") + geom_hline(yintercept = 0, col = "black") + 
                    labs(x = "Substrate Concentration (mM)", y = "[Substrate] / Velocity", title = "Woolf Hanes Plot of Enzymatic Inhibtion") + 
                    scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n=20), limits = c(-50,50)) + 
                    scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n=20)) + 
                    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", "purple"), name = "Inhibitor Concentration:") + 
                    scale_shape_manual(values = c(15,16,17,3), name = "Inhibitor Concentration:")
                  

# Add the fitted lines to the plot.
# Very redundant calls to the Competitive_Woolf_H_Function
# With the only difference being the Inhibitor Concentration is different
Woolf_Hanes_Plot_Fitted <- Woolf_Hanes_Plot + stat_function(size = 1, fun = Competitive_Woolf_H_Function, 
                                                            args = list(K_M = Parameters[[1]], K_I = Parameters[[2]], V_Max = Parameters[[3]], I = 0), 
                                                            col = "red") + 
                                              stat_function(size = 1, fun = Competitive_Woolf_H_Function, 
                                              args = list(K_M = Parameters[[1]], K_I = Parameters[[2]], V_Max = Parameters[[3]], I = 6), 
                                              col = "green") + 
                                              stat_function(size = 1, fun = Competitive_Woolf_H_Function, 
                                              args = list(K_M = Parameters[[1]], K_I = Parameters[[2]], V_Max = Parameters[[3]], I = 12), 
                                              col = "blue") + 
                                              stat_function(size = 1, fun = Competitive_Woolf_H_Function, 
                                              args = list(K_M = Parameters[[1]], K_I = Parameters[[2]], V_Max = Parameters[[3]], I = 24), 
                                              col = "violet")
print(Woolf_Hanes_Plot_Fitted)
```

Effectively what I have done is I have created a dataframe of `Inhibitor_Conc`, `Substrate_Conc`, and Velocity. I fit the model of Competitive Inhibition to this Enzyme Kinetics Data. I used nonlinear regression to extract the unknown parameters `K_M`, `K_I`, and `V_Max` that describe my dataset.

I then used those calculated parameters to create a function which returns values for the `Woolf_Hanes` Version of the competitive Inhibition function. The hallmark of this function is that whatever the parameters `K_M`, `K_I`, `V_Max` are the lines as function of Substrate Concentration will always be parallel.

The most inefficient part of my code is when I call stat_function 4 times, and manually specify I = 0 and then I = 6, I = 12, and I = 24. That's not very efficient calling stat_function 4 times with each of those inhibitor concentrations especially when the inhibitor concentrations are already in my plotted dataframe. I did this, though to demonstrate my desired output. How can I do this passing the `Substrate_Conc` and the `Inhibitor_Conc` into the function I call in `stat_function()`? Thank you!

The output of the nonlinear model yields the parameters:

```
Formula: velocity ~ (V_Max * Substrate_Conc)/(K_M * (1 + Inhibitor_Conc/K_I) + 
    Substrate_Conc)

Parameters:
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
K_M    6.81741    1.40083   4.867 0.000145 ***
K_I    7.64747    1.92212   3.979 0.000971 ***
V_Max  0.24724    0.01475  16.763 5.24e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01489 on 17 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.661e-06
```

Comment: This is all a bit domain specific so I didn't follow along exactly, but since ggplot accepts `+ list`, you could just do `+ mapply(function(param1, param2, param3){stat_function(fun = function(x){x * param1 * param2 * param3})}, param1 = 1:10, param2 = 2:11, param3 = 3:12, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`, wherein the exact function passed to `fun` argument and the `param*` arguments apply to your domain. I imagine them being the `V_Max` coefficients or something.

Comment: I can predict the quantities of the dependent variable S_over_V from -50 to 50 Substrate Concentration for all the inhibitor concentrations (0, 6, 12, 24) and the calculated parameters K_M, K_I, and V_Max, but I just can't figure out how to plot the prediction lines. 

I mean this gives me the values I need:

mapply(FUN = Competitive_Woolf_H_Function, S = c(-max(df$Substrate_Conc):max(df$Substrate_Conc)), K_M = Parameters[[1]], K_I = Parameters[[2]], V_Max = Parameters[[3]], MoreArgs = list(I = unique(df$Inhibitor_Conc)), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

But how do I put this into stat_function()?